# Chrome Extension - Chrome Alarm API rescheduling all alarm after for each new alarm created

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, alarm

I have developed chrome extension named Reminder App in which i have used Alarm API which allow user to set alarm , App has two section To create single reminder (e.g at 10:20 AM) and to create multiple reminder (e.g Every 50 Mins) , when in packaged App (After Uploading to webstore) i set two reminder

1.10:20 AM (at 10:18:10 AM)

2.Every 10 Min (at 10:19:10 AM)

In local (Unpackaged App) Both alarm trigger Exactly At 10:20 AM , but same Scenario In Packaged App First Alarm went off at 10:20 AM but second one went off at 10:21 AM (instead of 10:20 AM).

How can i make both of them synchronize?

Does it because of this Stated in [Alarm API Doc](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/alarms)?

In order to reduce the load on the user's machine, Chrome limits alarms to at most once every 1 minute but may delay them an arbitrary amount more. [...]

To help you debug your app or extension, when you've loaded it unpacked, there's no limit to how often the alarm can fire.

Comment: that quote seems pretty clear and explains your issue

Comment: @Zig Mandel isnt't there any other way so i can synchronize it ?

Comment: setTimeout and so on from background page

Comment: can you provide me exact code ? where and when i have to set it ? or give me reference if some one already used it.

Comment: that is too broad. look at arquitecture overview to understsnd background pages

Comment: If you want two alarms to fire at the same time, it seems you should have one alarm trigger two functions.

Comment: but the problem occur in packaged app only , if i set second reminder between (10:19:00 am to 10:20:00 am)  of first reminder (Schedule Time : 10:20:00 am) then  first reminder went off exactly one min late after we add second reminder , so if we add second reminder at 10:19:20 am then first reminder went of at 10:20:20 am insted of 10:20:00 am. alarm listener fire it at 10:20:20 am so how can i make alarm api to not reschedule alarm if i add an another alarm? my problem is some what like this https://codereview.chromium.org/145353013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using settimeout() or setinterval() function as suggested by @Zig Mandel , i m now no longer using chrome alarm API , i just stored data using Storage API and polling it every 1 sec using setinterval function in background page from storage.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [Alarm API Doc](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/alarms#method-create) and as you quoted:

> Chrome limits alarms to at most once every 1 minute but may delay them
>   an arbitrary amount more.

Another way which might work for you is by 'appending' the new reminder's text with the name of the alarm that have the same scheduledTime.

This can be done by checking if the new alarm will be matching any scheduledTime of all the alarms already set up. If so, you can clear that particular alarm and create a new one with the appended text. You can then handle the appended text when onAlarm() is fired.

[NOTE: I haven't tried this out]